# Writing integers into a new file

Tags: python, file, file-writing

So I am trying to open a new file, and write in to that file all the values of `n`.

```
for n in [4, 7, 8, 10, 6, 3, 5, 13]:
    if n > 5:
        print(n)
b = open('new', 'w')
b.write(n)
```

It writes the numbers in as a string and only writes in `13`, the last `n`.

Comment: I think you're opening the file with `w`, meaning 'write', and you're overwriting previous writes you do to that file. Try `a` for append, I think.

Comment: Also you're doing it **outside the loop**, after it has completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are printing the last value only. So you are getting the result only 13.You have to write the value in the for loop.

```
b = open('new', 'w')
for n in [4, 7, 8, 10, 6, 3, 5, 13]:
    if n > 5:
        print(n)
        b.write(n)
```

Comment: `write()` expects a character buffer object, and even you are not closing the file, run locally and then post!

Answer (score 1):

Modified code:

```
with open('new', 'w') as outfile:
    for n in [4, 7, 8, 10, 6, 3, 5, 13]:
        if n > 5:
            print(n)
            outfile.write(str(n))
```

or (Not recommended)

```
for n in [4, 7, 8, 10, 6, 3, 5, 13]:
    if n > 5:
        print(n)
        b = open('new', 'a') # append mode
        b.write(str(n))
        b.close()
```